# Custom error message in Django admin actions

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've written custom admin actions that basically do `QuerySet.update()` for certain fields in the model. There are times when these actions shouldn't be allowed to complete -- instead, they should display an error and not do anything. I've tried `message_user`, but that displays a green checkmark, whereas I'd like it to display the Django admin error message.

A solution I've found online is to use a `ModelForm`, but I don't think that applies in this case, as here everything happens on the admin change list page.

Answer (score 53):

The `message_user` function used within the admin simply uses the `contrib.messages` package. You could try something like this:

```
from django.contrib import messages

# Then, when you need to error the user:
messages.error(request, "The message")
```

You can also use `warning`, `debug`, `info` and `success` in place of `error`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Bartek. Using this code, I was still stumped why my messages were not showing up as error messages in the admin, until I found that an app in my path (django-admin-tools, in this case) was overriding the admin/base.html template, but had not updated the message outputting html to add the appropriate class to each message. If you're messages are broken, make sure your admin templates reflect the latest (django 1.2) updates.

Comment: Hi, Bartek, I tried to do that but didn't work. The message is printed with a green checkmark yet.

zlovelady, I have updated the admin templates but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: This doesn't address "and not do anything" part.  For example, if a model's save throws an exception, the error should be displayed and the model shouldn't be saved.  Using this answer, the error is indeed displayed correctly, but the green success message still follows the red error message.  How can the success message be prevented from being displayed?

Answer (score 53):

```
from django.contrib import messages
...
self.message_user(request, "The message", level=messages.ERROR)
```

Сan also be used (messages.ERROR, messages.WARNING, messages.DEBUG, messages.INFO, messages.SUCCESS)

Answer (score 5):

You can use django.contrib.messages backend

```
from django.contrib import messages

def my_action(self, request, queryset):
  #do something
  messages.error(request,'Error message')
```

This will show the error message and the red error sign.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure whether this was fixed in newer django versions (I found the behaviour you described in django 1.2.1 and also in django-grappelli 2.0), but if you use Bartek's method above, you'd also probably want to change the admin templates to show the messages differently. Specifically in base.html:

Change this:

```
{% if messages %}
        <ul class="messagelist">{% for message in messages %}<li>{{ message }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>
    {% endif %}
```

to this:

```
{% if messages %}
        <ul class="messagelist">{% for message in messages %}<li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message}}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>
    {% endif %}
```

You might still need to tweak some CSS on top of that too, but at least it would come up as a different li class on the HTML.

Here's a sample CSS change (compatible with grappelli)

```
ul.messagelist li.error {
background: url('../img/icons/icon-no.png') 20px 50% no-repeat;
background-color: #f2e6e6;

}
```